# find still exits with result code 0, even if nothing found on -mmin parameter

Tags: linux, bash

I'm using `find` to check if a file was modified within the last minute.

The strange thing is that this does not return any result, if the find exists but is older than 1 minute. However, the reported exit code is still 0, not 1, as I would expect (and need it).

```
$ find /tmp/healthy -mmin -1
$ echo $?
0   # <-- I expected this to be 1
```

I have a workaround with piping to grep, but I'm wondering if there is a built-in way/parameter to make `find` return 1 directly.

Workaround so far:

```
$ find /tmp/healthy -mmin -1 | grep .
$ echo $?
1
```

Comment: Well, your expectation is wrong. This is how `find` is supposed to operate. If you *want* do use `find` for this task, store the result of find into a variable and test, whether the variable is empty. If you need the information just about one specific file, it's more natural to read the modification timestamp of this file and compare it to the current time. BTW: `find` does produce a non-zero exit code if there is an actual error - in your case, if /tmp/healthy does not exist.

Comment: BTW: `find` does produce a non-zero exit code if there is an actual error - in your case, if /tmp/healthy does not exist.